# RHEL 8 - How can I modify an ethernet device name?

Tags: linux, rhel, ethernet, ifconfig, nmcli

I am trying to modify the ethernet device name without modifying grub. I have tried to modify the device name, but when I do, the device stops working.

Things I have tried:

- I've tried [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/nmcli-connection-questions-4175616996/)

```
nmcli con edit id "Wired connection 1"
set connection.id testname
save
quit
```

- I've also tried this:

```
nmcli connection modify ens33 connection.id testname
```

But neither of those change the device name, which is what I need (so I can access the device with `ifconfig` or `ip addr`)

- I've also tried [this](https://tekneed.com/how-to-rename-nic-in-linux-centos-rhel-7-8/)

```
ifdown ens33
ifconfig ens33 down
ip link set ens33 name testname
mv /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-testname
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-testname
ifconfig testname up
ifup testname
```

which appears to work at first glance because i can access the device with ifconfig, but after I bring the interface back up it fails to ping the target device (although it can ping itself).

The answer on this page looks promising, but I can't access it: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/108823

I must be missing a step, does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the name of my network interface caused my mac address to change, therefore it would fail at the mac layer. By hardcoding the mac address into the */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-testname* file using the *HWADDR* directive, then the interface name change would work just fine; (It failed when I used the *MACADDR* directive).

This failed:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-testname
MACADDR=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

This succeeded:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-testname
HWADDR=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

> found helpful info here:
> https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/consistent-network-interface-device-naming_configuring-and-managing-networking#how-the-network-device-naming-works_consistent-network-interface-device-naming

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the page says:

Modify the file /etc/modprobe.conf replacing ifcfg-eth0 with ifcfg-dev123:

```
alias dev123 e1000
```

In the directory /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ rename the file ifcfg-eth0 to ifcfg-dev123.

```
# cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
# mv ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-dev123
```

Edit the ifcfg-dev123 file replacing eth0 to dev123 in DEVICE= parameter:

```
DEVICE=dev123
```

If the system-config-network* tools were used, it may be necessary to remove any file referencing the old device in the /etc/sysconfig/networking directory. ie.

```
# find /etc/sysconfig/networking -name ifcfg-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/ifcfg-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0

# mv /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/ifcfg-eth0 /root
# mv /etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0 /root
```

After this procedure, restart your server or your network interface:

```
# ifup dev123
```

Personally, I've had success with modifying `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interfacename>`. You move the file to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-testname` and update the `DEVICE` field in the file to match: `DEVICE=testname`. Then reboot the server. This looks similar to the second thing you tried though.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same results: still can't ping devices connected to the interface.

Comment: Which version of RHEL are you on?

Comment: Your nftables/iptables ruleset might include rules specified by interface name. If you change the name of the interface without updating the firewall rules accordingly, the traffic of the renamed interface is likely to hit the catch-all "deny everything" standard rule at the end of the ruleset, because the interface name no longer matches. (Both `iptables` and `nftables` allow creating FW rules for non-existent interfaces, because you may want to pre-define rules for an interface you're planning to hot-plug later.)

Comment: turned out to be the mac layer